# How to write SQL Query for this condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have 2 tables one is "Batch" and another one is "BatchDetails".
Batch have columns like BatchId,BatchName, and TechId.
BatchDetails have columns like BatchDetailsId,BatchId and SubTechID.

BatchDetails table is connected with Batch table by "BatchId".
There is One to Many relationship between "Batch" and "BatchDetail" Table.
One Batch have multiple entries in BatchDetails Table.

Now i want to select all BatchName from Batch where TechId=1 and corresponding to that BatchName, BatchDetails table have SubTechId=1 and SubTechId=2.

Comment: Why is this tagged Oracle *and* MySQL?

Comment: Justin, are you wanting a query for each Query Language, or what?  Please specify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several approaches to returning the specified result.

Assuming that the specification is to return *only* rows from `batch` that have at least two associated rows in `batchdetails`, and at least one of those associated rows is `subtechid=1` and at least one with `subtechid=2`

For MySQL:

```
 SELECT b.batchname 
   FROM batch b
   JOIN batchdetail d1
     ON d1.batchid = b.batchid
    AND d1.subtechid = 1
   JOIN batchdetail d2
     ON d2.batchid = b.batchid
    AND d2.subtechid = 2
  WHERE b.techid = 1
  GROUP BY b.batchid
  ORDER BY b.batchname
```

It's also possible to get an equivalent result using `EXISTS` predicates:

```
 SELECT b.batchname
   FROM batch b
  WHERE b.techid = 1
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM batchdetail d1
                  WHERE d1.batchid = b.batchid
                    AND d1.subtechid = 1
                )
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM batchdetail d2
                  WHERE d2.batchid = b.batchid
                    AND d2.subtechid = 2
                )
  ORDER BY b.batchname
```

or, getting a count of distinct values of subtechid and comparing to a constant

```
 SELECT b.batchname
   FROM batch b
   JOIN batchdetail d
     ON d.batchid = b.batchid
    AND d.subtechid IN (1,2)
  WHERE b.techid = 1 
  GROUP BY b.batchid 
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.subtechid) = 2 
  ORDER BY b.batchname
```

There are several other query patterns...